# How do I find the uppercase letter in the middle of a word, in the middle of a sentence in Excel?

Tags: worksheet-function

I'm trying to find an Excel formula which will tell me where in a sentence in a cell, does an uppercase letter appear in the middle of a "word". I want to then use that position to pull the text to the right of that position.

For example:

Cell A1 = The red carYellow space
A2 = The pink bikeRed space
A3 = The green truckBlue space

I need a formula that would extract "Yellow space", and "Red space" and "Blue space".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the cell starts with an uppercase (like in your example) you can do that with an array formula that utilizes the ASCII character values for all the uppercase letters (from 65 to 90).

Use this in `B1`:
`=REPLACE(A1,1,MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(CHAR(ROW($65:$90)),REPLACE(A1, 1, 1, ""))),FIND(CHAR(ROW($65:$90)),REPLACE(A1, 1, 1, "")))),"")`

*This is an array formula, so you need to enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, not just Enter. And then drag down to fill the whole coulmn.*

Comment: Thank you. That works for the example above. What about if it was written The red CarYellow space? So a mix of capitals? Unfortunately, I have no control over what someone enters into the system. But I have to work with the output :(

Comment: But do you know the words that start the output you want? It's always Blue/Red/Yellow?